# The system cannot find the path specified. (exec php)

Tags: php, exec

I feel this problem is very simple

I want to convert `pdf` file to image `png`.

Using easyphp:

```
$gp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe ";
$gp = escapeshellarg($gp);
echo $gp;
echo exec($gp. " upload\pdf_file\545-1.pdf  upload\pdf_image\54.png 2>&1");
```

It gives an error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

However, if I execute only `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe`

It works. But with argument in it, it gives that error.

Comment: Try the absolute path to the file, not the relative.

Comment: i just remove C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\
error Invalid Parameter - upload\pdf_image\62.png

Comment: I'm talking about the **full path** to the PDF file.

Comment: hi thanks 
i tryed this
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe   F:\system folder\Bureau\linkabee\work\php\upload\pdf_file\755-1.pdf   F:\system folder\Bureau\linkabee\work\php\upload\pdf_image\75.png "
 this the error
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

i finally got work

```
 $gp= "C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe ";
    $ch=" upload\\pdf_file\\135-1.pdf";
    $ch.=" upload\\pdf_image\\1.png";

     $gp=escapeshellarg($gp);
     echo exec($gp.$ch." 2>&1");
```